# CSS animation with multiple transforms but without nested divs

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/joeypclausen/dkkwe54g/1/) is the effect that I want, but is there a way to do it without nested divs? I have tried to combine the transforms, but either I'm missing something simple, or I just need to us JavaScript or jQuery to add and remove classes?

Here is my attempt at combining

```
.spin{
-webkit-animation: scaleup .5s 1 forwards,
                   rotate .6s linear .7s 2,
                   scaledown 1.5s 2.0s 1 forwards;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, seven years later, you could think on an approach like the one proposed by "vsync" user in this other post for other problem:

[CSS animate custom properties/variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661638/css-animate-custom-properties-variables)

The idea would be to animate only css vars (with @property) in your "single" animations (scaleup, rotate, scaledown), and have a final animation with just one css transform using those animated values.

@property seems not to be wide supported on browsers (Chrome allows it, i think), and this is only an idea of a possible approach that could or could not work.

If someone test this, please, let us know ;)