# CSS animate custom properties/variables

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-variables

I have been trying to get this to work for a while.

The point is that the inner div will have some shape and there will probably more than one (That's why I used the `nth-child` selector).
This inner div is supposed to be shown and then be hidden again both for some set amount of time.
the problem is, that I would like to animate all the (later) multiple inner divs in one animation. For this I thought I could use CSS variables, but this does not seem to work.

What I am trying to archieve in this example is the inner div basically just blinking by using the variable. But my result in Firefox is just a black box.

Am I missing anything? I already looked up if one could even use CSS variables in `@keyframes` and sure enough you can.
The only problem with them in animations seems to be that they are not interpolated in between but that they suddenly switch which is not a problem in this case.

```css
@keyframes test{
    from{
        --one: 0;
    }
    to{
        --one: 1;
    }
}

#test{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    animation: test 1s infinite;
}
#test :nth-child(1){
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: var(--one,0);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This can be achieved by defining variables using (as of writing this, not well-supported) [`@property`](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property), which allows declaring **types** and that allows the browser to "understand", for example, that a certain property (variable) is a *Number* and then it can gradually animate/transition that variable.

#### Example Code:

```css
@property --opacity {
  syntax: '<number>'; /* <- defined as type number for the transition to work */
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  50% {--opacity: 1}
}

html {
  animation: 2s fadeIn infinite;
  background: rgba(0 0 0 / var(--opacity));
}
```

The current types that are allowed include:

`length`, `number`, `percentage`, `length-percentage`, `color`, `image`, `url`, `integer`, `angle`, `time`, `resolution`, `transform-list`, `transform-function`, `custom-ident` (an identifier string)

---

### Helpful articles:

1. https://web.dev/at-property/#writing-houdini-custom-properties
2. https://css-tricks.com/using-property-for-css-custom-properties
3. [Cool Houdini demos](https://css-houdini.rocks/corners-gradient)

Comment: cool, looking for that, and not find the MDN reference

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Houdini

Comment: Do you have any hints on how I could debug this? I think the property is not getting registered correctly for me. But I'm on Chrome 101 so it should be supported...

Comment: This works for me in Chrome but not in Firefox (v121).

Answer (score 11):

As stated in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/):

> Animatable:    no

and also

> Notably, they can even **be transitioned or animated**, but since the UA
> **has no way to interpret their contents**, they always use the "flips at
> 50%" behavior that is used for any other pair of values that can’t be
> intelligently interpolated. However, any **custom property used in a**
> **@keyframes rule becomes animation-tainted**, which affects how it is
> treated when referred to via the var() function in an animation
> property.

---

So even if you use `opacity` with `var()` in the keyframes it won't animate:

```css
@keyframes test {
  from {
    --one:0;
    opacity: var(--one);
  }
  to {
    opacity: var(--one);
    --one: 1;
  }
}

#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#test :nth-child(1) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  animation: test 1s  infinite;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

By the way you can make it working if you use it as a `transition` because in this case you will apply a transtion to the opacity and not the custom property:

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#test:hover {
  --one:1;
}

#test :nth-child(1) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: var(--one,0);
  transition:1s all;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought that _use the "flips at 50%" behavior_ would apply here. Why doesn't it? Because as I said that would be perfectly fine in this case.
Maybe I don't understand _animation tainted_ correctly.

Comment: @Johann150 to be honest the *animation tainted* is also confusing e :) I was searching a lot for this as me too I want to be able to animate custom property but after a lot of research, this was the only Specification section where I found it's not possible when using inside keyframes. BTW, let's wait, maybe you will get more answers ;)

Comment: Facing [a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64218743/), and if I read the quoted text and the specs correctly, the `animation-tainted` thing only applies to the `var()` value when used in the `animation` property, it shouldn't affect the ones in the `@keyframes`, even though having it in the `@keyframes` is what makes it tainted for `animation`. [Here is where it's being used](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#substitute-a-var). (Maybe it's a workaround for what could have been a source of infinite loop?). Note that your first example works perfectly fine in Firefox.

Comment: @Kaiido that issue cannot be in this scope because you are not animating any of the Custom properties but you are animating rotate(). In this case there is no animation-tainted. Even if you use `var()` inside `animation` there is also no animation-tainted behavior .. The specs says *However, any custom property used in a @keyframes rule becomes animation-tainted* --> it means used like `--c:1` and not like `property:var(-c)`. The last one is Ok.

Comment: I didn't mean the "related issue" was the same, only related and it's to give an idea of why I came here (an other discrepancy between browsers). My point is that "So even if you use opacity with var() in the keyframes it won't animate" is not true, or at least is not implied by the quote before. The quote only says that if you did `--foo: 2s; animation: anim-name var(--foo) infinite; } @keyframes anim-name { from { --foo: 0s } to { --foo: 15s } }` the value used in `animation: anim-name var(--foo) infinite; }` would remain `2s`. It doesn't say that `opacity` should not use the updated value.

Comment: The specs say  "*which affects how it is treated when referred to via the var() function in an **`animation`** property*", not in anywhere else. (actually I since then found [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5341) where it's stated that `display` is also concerned "under some conditions" and that all `non-animatable` will be.

Comment: So to be clear, your misunderstanding stands in the fact you thought that "*becomes animation-tainted*" meant its value was somehow locked in that @keyframes context, while what really happens is that when this flag is set it only blocks the [substitute a var](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#substitute-a-var) algorithm, only for the `animation` property. The first one is also ok for the specs.

Comment: @Kaiido *My point is that "So even if you use opacity with var() in the keyframes it won't animate" is not true,* --> it's true considering the first explanaton where it says *UA has no way to interpret their contents*. I am using this part to explain why they cannot have transtion and animation (both of them). I said there is no *animation-tained* in the other question because you are not using any custom property inside the keyframes so that sentence doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: @Kaiido we cannot animate/transition custom property because it's hard for borwser to understand their content (integer, float, string, etc). The animation-tainted thing is a extra conclusion in case you are using the custom property inside the keyframes

Comment: @Temani no and no :-) you can very well animate custom properties in a keyframe, it just will use the "flips at 50%". The animation-tainted thing is not for when the custom property is used in a keyframe, it is for when it is used in an `animation-`, and soon will be for when it's used in a non-animatable property. The @keyframes context is just what triggers the tainting of the custom property, but in neither your example this custom property is used in an `animation-` rule, so even of it is *animation-tainted*, it has no effect on your code at all. Your first snippet and OP should animate.

Comment: @Kaiido well, the Spec clearly said `animatable: No` (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#defining-variables) so they aren't meant to be animated (at least in current Spec). Browser may decide to do it differently in some case but it's a *No* unless you are lucky to find a working example.
For the animation tainted, it's a different story and I said it's out of the scope because in your keyframes there is no `--c:something` (this is what I called *used in keyframes*). I am not using it to explain the non-animatlbe thing (probably not using good english to explain this well)

Comment: Once again I never said the related issue was the same thing. You are not understanding how the `animation-tainted ` flag works and that's why I'm trying to explain to you that it has nothing to do in your answer here.  The fact a custom variable is not animatable only means it will have a "flips at 50%" behavior. Even your quote says plain: "*Notably, they can even be transitioned or animated*"