# Is it possible to do CSS transition for custom property?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I am playing around with paintWorklet. I wonder if it is possible do transition on the custom property?

```css
.hello {
  --chessBoardSize: 20;
  background-image: paint(helloWorld);
  transition: 1s;
}

.hello:hover {
  --chessBoardSize: 30;
}
```

The hover works, but it just change `--chessBoardSize` from 20 to 30 without any smooth transition.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63674883/8620333