# CSS keyframe animation not working Safari

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a border gradient animation implemented with just CSS. It works fine on Chrome but not Safari or Firefox either. Any ideas how to make it work across Safari

```css
.animated {
  --angle: 0deg;
  width: 75vmin;
  height: auto;
  border-left: 4em solid;
  border-bottom: 3em solid;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  border-image: conic-gradient(from var(--angle), red, yellow, lime, aqua, blue, magenta, red) 1;
  animation: 10s rotate linear infinite;
  border-radius: 40px
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    --angle: 360deg;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  to {
    --angle: 360deg;
  }
}

@property --angle {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}

-webkit-appearance --angle {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
  <div style="padding:0.25em;text-align: left !important" align="left">some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is support for CSS variable animation on Firefox yet

Comment: Safari has support for animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually it's not the only issue, at least for FF. They kind of support animating the --var but you also need to append the rule where the variable is being used. However they just don't support animating gradient's angle. And it seems Safari just doesn't animate <image> at all (not even flip...)

Comment: @Kaiido it's not about the animation in general, it's about the `@property`. This one is supported on Firefox and Safari (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property#browser_compatibility) and it's the feature that will simulate the gradient (or angle) animation. No browser support <image> animation but with this new feature they can animate the variable that will reflect an <image> animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif right so it's neither the animation of the variable, neither the animation of the gradient but the support for TypedOM. Sounds kike an answer, except of you know a dupe?. However note that FF does support animating <image>, by using flip (so no transition)

Comment: @Kaiido probably this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54594167/8620333 (where we already discuss about support) but I was thinking that we can probably find a workaround for this particular case wihout using variable at all (I have an idea that I will try shortly)

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you want to spend some more time on this, in the hope it gives you other ideas or if you want to take it as it, it's fine with me: here I made a version of your answer that actually works on FF and Safari using a solid background hack for the text (positions are off but...): https://jsfiddle.net/182udf4o And here is an other idea: https://jsfiddle.net/182udf4o/2/ I think a bit closer to OP's animation, but a lot more dirty too (couldn't find the correct timing to have the lateral gradients to "shrink" like border-image does...)

Comment: @Kaiido worth adding as an answer ;) especially the last one .. I gave up on my idea because I saw that Firefix is buggy with it and I have no Safari browser to test and I'd image it will be worse there.