# CSS transition scale() - weird delay

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Run the code snippet below - clicking on the circle to toggle the animation. What should be happening is, the child should appear as if it's not moving as the parent container scales.

This is achieved by scaling down the child component at the same ratio that the parent is scaled up (parent scaled to 4, child scales to 0.25).

When the animation is complete the scale is correct, however during the animation it looks like they are not scaling in unison.

It's almost as if the parent scales first, then once complete the child scales.

Is this some sort of browser limitation? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Thanks!**

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('outer--active');
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }

.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer--active {
  transform: scale(4) translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/14.jpg') center repeat;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.outer--active .inner {
  transform: scale(0.25) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The problem

What you see is not "browser bug", but rather a misunderstanding of how the calculation of two combined scaling works.

For simplicity, lets assume that the transition function is `linear` (and not `ease`, which is the default timing function). In that case the, the plots of both scales would be as follows:
[image: scaling functions]

Since we want to get the final scale of inner element to remain constant, then the (scale up function) × (scale down function) = 1 for all time arguments. Unfortunately, if we do the multiplication, as a result we get a square function (in our case it is -¾x² + 3x + ¾). This is the bump in final scaling that you can see in the middle of transition. In order to avoid that, instead of transitioning the `scale(n)` value, we would need to scale the `m` in `scale(1/m)` css rule. Unfortunately, we can't do this, even if we used css variables, as these do not (yet) allow for transitions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661638/css-animate-custom-properties-variables) answer)

To alleviate that, we could craft a custom `cubic-bezier` timing function that would be the inverse of the square function, but I was unable to do so manually, and probably `cubic-bezier` would not give the exact curve for all time values, especially if we wanted to have the base timing function anything other than `linear`.

## The solution

Approach 1: Instead of scaling, we could change the dimensions of the outer div, as shown below:

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('outer--active');
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }

.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer--active {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/14.jpg') center repeat;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Pros: retains the current html markup structure

Cons: the animation is choppy due to browser bugs regarding sub-pixel transition smoothing (e.g. [firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176))

---

Approach 2: Use clipping mask for the circular cutout effect, add div for the border:

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('outer--active');
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }

.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rim {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: all 1s;
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.outer--active .rim {
    transform: scale(4)  translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/14.jpg') center repeat;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: all 1s;
  clip-path: circle(50px at 200px 200px);
}

.outer--active .inner {
  clip-path: circle(200px at 200px 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="rim"></div>
</div>
```

Pros: scales smoothly

Cons: need to add another html tag for the circular border/rim. The rim may sometimes look disjointed from the inner image.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough breakdown - very well explained. I avoided width and height scaling due to the performance and clip-path because it just doesn't have the browser compatibility I require yet. Looks like I will need to think of an alternative transition. Thanks again!

Comment: nice, first time I see a complete answer without even an edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is similar ideas like the other answer where you can do this with only one element.

Increasing width/height.

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('outer--active');
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }

.outer {
  width: calc(100px * var(--s,1));
  height: calc(100px * var(--s,1));
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: 
    url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/14.jpg') center ;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer--active {
  --s:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
```

Considering `clip-path` where I add a `radial-gradient` to create the border

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('outer--active');
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }

.outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - 3px),#000 100%),
    url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/14.jpg');
  background-size:40% 40%,auto;
  background-position:center;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(20% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(20% at 50% 50%);
}

.outer--active {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  background-size:100% 100%,auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
```

You can also consider only `radial-gradient` but the area of the click will be bigger and you won't have transparency:

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

outer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('outer--active');
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }

.outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(40% - 3px),#000 40%,#fff calc(40% + 1px)),
    url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/14.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%,auto;
  background-position:center;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.outer--active {
  background-size:240% 240%,auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
```