# CSS animation with CSS variables and @keyframes not updating on Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, repaint

I'm doing an animation with CSS variables, where a CSS variable value changes based on the page scroll. That variable is then used on animation with keyframes.

Originally it's updating correctly only on Firefox. Meanwhile, I found a way to make it work on Chrome too, by forcing a repaint, in this case, animate the color from #000 to #001.

```css
/* --scale is dynamic changed by JS */

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) scale(var(--scale));
        color: #000;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(33vw) scale(1.5);
        color: #001;
    }
}
```

You can see [a demo at codepen](https://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/eYYovvZ)

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: @DimitarSpassov, my workaround was to create 2 animations: The original one a an `moveExpensive` where I used `left` instead of `translateX`, forcing the repaint. Then with JS detect the browser. If it's FF use `move`, otherwise use `moveExpensive`.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but on Safari the issue remains, even if I replace the `translateX` transformation with `left`.

Comment: Oh sorry, @DimitarSpassov, forgot to mention, I didn't use variables on the fallback version. In my case, I used hardcoded values (%) and did some other workarounds. In summary: I didn't find a way to make it work with CSS variables.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animate custom properties/variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661638/css-animate-custom-properties-variables)

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into this issue and solved it by setting the `element.style.animation` attribute in JavaScript after calling `setProperty()`. It seems like `@keyframes` doesn't update after setting the `animation` in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

This is a WebKit bug. I discovered this issue today by reading [Safari Technology Preview 149 changelog,](https://webkit.org/blog/12998/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-149/) which means it should be fixed in Safari 16, to be released later this year.

> Added support for custom properties in @keyframes rules ([251733@main](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/9a200620bb6f1f1ea66222ee5be2d6bd58b8da67))

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for those (like myself) who are using Styled Component's keyframes`` function, you can exchange the css variable for a prop by defining a function much like the following:

```
import styled, { Keyframes, keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const move = (scale: number): Keyframes => keyframes`
  0% {
      transform: translateX(0) scale(${scale});
      color: #000;
  }
  100% {
      transform: translateX(33vw) scale(1.5);
      color: #001;
  }
`

const AnimatedElement = styled.div<{ scale: number }>`
  animation: ${(props) => move(props.scale)} 2s linear infinite;
`
```