# CSS Variables in keyframes

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I try to animate at keyframes with variables, but instead of animation i get a slide show

[Example is here](https://codepen.io/zloigoroh/pen/KKvyqoP)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="red-square animation"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.red-square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

/* this is working */
.animation {
    animation: complex-animation 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes complex-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translate(50px, -50px) rotate(20deg);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate(-50px, -50px) rotate(-20deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
}



/* and this is not */
.var-animation {
    --x-translate: 0px;
    --y-translate: 0px;
    --rotation: 0deg;
    transform: translate(var(--x-translate), var(--y-translate)) rotate(var(--rotation));
    animation: var-animation 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes var-animation {
    0% {
        --x-translate: 0px;
        --y-translate: 0px;
        --rotation: 0deg;
    }

    25% {
        --x-translate: 50px;
        --y-translate: -50px;
        --rotation: 20deg;
    }

    50% {
        --x-translate: -50px;
        --y-translate: -50px;
        --rotation: -20deg;
    }

    100% {
        --x-translate: 0px;
        --y-translate: 0px;
        --rotation: 0deg;
    }
}
```

This is not a huge problem here, but for really complex animations with many functions in `translate` it's very hard to work without variables and to edit such code.
Can you explain why does it happen and is it possible to use variables for animations.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661638/css-animate-custom-properties-variables

Comment: That's definitely what i need, thank you