# Hue rotate changes the image and not the drop shadow

Tags: html, css

So I have this problem where i only want to animate the drop shadow to change the drop shadow and not the whole img.

```css
img {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgb(255, 0, 0));
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/9d28d100-7cfa-4b00-b958-c6be005e62c4/87de3a763609657f3950e8e0829291f4-removebg-preview.png">
```

Comment: This could be useful. You could make the drop-shadow colour a variable and then animate the colour change by animating the change of the variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661638/css-animate-custom-properties-variables

Comment: You need to apply multiple filters

Comment: Theoretically we should have been able to apply the drop-shadow filter on a second element with enough offset to show only this drop-shadow and hide the original content in an overflow, allowing to show the "original" content untouched over it. However browsers refuse to draw the drop-shadow after a certain offset (not sure why, the weird thing is different browsers seem to agree when to stop working...). https://jsfiddle.net/ng9e703z/ Note that if your image doesn't have semit-transparency (so either fully opaque or fully transparent), this may still work, with an offset of 0)

Comment: Would a non-CSS solution (e.g canvas) be viable for you? (if so you may want to tag your question with [javascript]). Or even would a solution that would work only in latest Chromium based browsers be a viable solution? (This would be doable with the Paint API).

Comment: Note for myself in case I get an anwser and to file bug reports where needed: version that works in FF and Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/r2c4qm68/1 and one that works in FF and Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/r2c4qm68/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could try animating changes of color of the drop shadow itself.

```css
img {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgb(255, 0, 0));
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgb(255, 0, 0));
    }
    25%
    {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgb(0, 255, 0));
    }
    50% {
      filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgb(0, 0, 255));
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgb(255, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/9d28d100-7cfa-4b00-b958-c6be005e62c4/87de3a763609657f3950e8e0829291f4-removebg-preview.png">
```

However, this does mean explicitly giving which colors you want it to transition to instead of just being able to rotate the color 360 degrees. (Using HSL instead of RGB doesn't solve this problem.)

Comment: this won't change the colors of the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's what is being asked