# transfrom: translate() vs translate property

Tags: html, css, animation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50vh - 100px);
        left: calc(50vw - 100px);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      .ball {
        transform-origin: center;
        width: 5%;
        height: 5%;
        margin-top: 0.8%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        animation: location 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.59, 0.99) 0s infinite
            alternate,
          size 3s linear;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        --y: 0px;
      }
      .animateBackward {
        animation-direction: alternate-reverse, reverse;
        --y: 115%;
      }
      .line {
        width: 10%;
        height: 1.3%;
        margin-top: -3%;
        margin-left: 45%;
        animation: lineSpin calc(3s / 4) cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.59, 0.99);
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }

      @keyframes location {
        0% {
          translate: 400% var(--y);
        }

        100% {
          translate: 1500% var(--y);
        }
      }

      @keyframes size {
        0% {
        }
        25% {
          transform: scale(1.5);
        }
        50% {
          transform: scale(1);
        }
        75% {
          transform: scale(0.5);
        }
        100% {
        }
      }

      @keyframes lineSpin {
        0% {
          transform: scaleX(5.6);
        }
        100% {
          transform: scaleX(0);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const redJump = 2.5;
    const greenJump = 3;
    const blueJump = -11;
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    [...Array(15)].forEach((_, i) => {
      const color = `rgb(${65 + redJump * i}, ${184 + greenJump * i}, ${
        212 + blueJump * i
      })`;
      container.innerHTML += `
      <div class="ball" style="animation-delay: -${
        250 * i
      }ms; background-color: ${color}"></div>
      ${
        i > 0
          ? `<div class="line" style="animation-delay: -${
              250 * i
            }ms; background-color: ${color}"></div>`
          : ''
      }
      <div class="ball animateBackward" style="animation-delay: -${
        250 * (i + 1)
      }ms; background-color: ${color}"></div>`;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Hey, I'm trying to create DNA animation and I wrote this code (using Chrome 104) and it all works fine. When I tried it in Chrom 90 I found out that the animation of the ball `location` `keyframes` is not working. I read that the `translate` property works only from Chrome 104 so I changed it to `transform: translate()` which is said in mdn that is exactly the same. But in practice is not.

How can I make my animation works properly in Chrome 90?

Hope you can help me figure out what is the problem and solve it :)

Reading in mdn and find out that the chrome version is the problem

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: How can I solve it and make my animation works properly?

Comment: 1.using Js. 2.using the same keyframe for both scale and translate : `transform: scale(foo) translate(bar);` 3. [animating a css property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661638/css-animate-custom-properties-variables) , [(which also doesn't have full support)](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_property)  or even combining this and `translate: x;` using [`@supports` At-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) for better support

Comment: Honestly, we are at chrome 107+ now, I wouldn't even worry about older chromes since it updates automatically.

Comment: Which way is the best? And can you help me with the code example?