# CSS: How to apply transition to variable

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms, css-variables

So I have this spinning crystal that spins at one revolution per 10 seconds, but while the mouse is hovering over it I want the seconds per revolution to gradually ramp down to 5 seconds, ie. spin faster. Right now I seem to have gotten the variable to change whenever the crystal is hovered, but it does so abruptly, even though this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661705/21862577) proves that transitions work with variables. However, for mine, it just abruptly flips from `1` to `2`, and it changes the rotation of the crystal to as if the variable was `2` all along, like some separate thread was running all this time. I should also mention that I **CANNOT** use JS because I am making a style for a fandom wiki that cannot use JS

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/ef1c72uo/

What I have so far:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amarante&display=swap');
#crystal__ #crystal-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53%;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/tYncDJ8/image.png);
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /*
  
  background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/Pzw7LSR/image.png);
  position:absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px rgb(255,150,50)) hue-rotate(180deg);
  */
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateZ(.825em) translateY(-.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(.825em) translateY(-.15em) rotateX(18.4deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(.825em) translateY(-.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(.825em) translateY(-.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateY(-5em) translateZ(.825em) translateY(.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-5em) translateZ(.825em) translateY(.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-5em) translateZ(.825em) translateY(.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ #crystal-side:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-5em) translateZ(.825em) translateY(.15em) rotateX(18.4deg);
}

#crystal__ {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 66%;
  left: 16.5%;
  transform-origin: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: crystal 10s linear infinite;
  transition: 2s all
}

@keyframes crystal {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(calc(360deg*var(--crroin)));
  }
  transition: 2s all
}

@property --crroin {
  syntax: '<number>';
  /* <- defined as type number for the transition to work */
  initial-value: 1;
  inherits: false;
}

#crystal-container {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 10em;
  float: left;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

#crystal-glow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(1.2);
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GF64XLK/qgwas.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%
}

#crystal-text {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(1em);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Amarante;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

body {
  font-size: 50px
}

#crystal-container:hover>#crystal-text {
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(1em) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(-24deg);
}

#crystal-container:hover>#crystal__ {
  --crroin: 2
}

#crystal-rack {
  float: none
}
```

```html
<div id="crystal-rack">
  <div id="crystal-container">
    <div id="crystal__">
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
      <div id="crystal-side"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="crystal-glow"></div>
    <div id="crystal-text">Places</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question. Links to other sites may be inaccessible and/or rot at any moment.

Comment: I don't think it can work this way. You have no idea _where_ in the currently running animation you are, when the hover state starts to apply. So you are changing how many rotations you want to perform, in the middle of the running animation - that just can't have a "well-defined" result, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, I know my pipeline isn't the correct one, it's just a starter, how do I make it work?

Comment: Maybe you could nest two elements into each other, and then switch which one gets animated? Have the inner element do the "normal" rotation, and then when the whole thing gets hovered, pause that inner animation, and un-pause the slower animation on the outer element instead. I think that could at least help alleviate the problems resulting from not knowing "where" in its cycle the animation currently is.

Comment: I don't want it to be abrupt though, I want it to slowly ease into a fast rotation from a slow rotation when hovered and back.